# min-height css property affecting multicolumn layout in text in an unexpected way

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

My problem: I'd like to set a `min-height` to a text container `<div>` with columns.

This `min-height` should affect the whole `div`, as usual, so regardless of the text inside, the `div` would always be at least the specified height.

However, when I assign a min-height property to a multi-column text container, the `min-height` is interpreted as kind of the *maximum column height* for reasons I don't understand.

Please take a look at the JSFIDDLE.

Why does this happen?

https://jsfiddle.net/pnjurqot/1/

The style for the container is:

```
.withcolumns {
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-gap: 20px;
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 20px;
    position:relative;
    display:block;
}

.minheight {
    background-color:red;
    min-height:100px;
    color:white;
}
```

so if I do:

```
<div class="withcolumns">
.
. long text
.
</div>
```

it works as expected, but if I set the min-height it fails:

```
<div class="withcolumns minheight">
.
. long text that gets clipped to min-height
.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it only happens on Chrome. It works fine on Firefox and IE.

It is Chrome that interprets min-height on columns differently, which defines the height of the column instead of the height with insufficient content.

That is, it may be a browser-dependent CSS code or a Chrome bug.

Comment: do you think it's a bug? By all means chrome is mistaking min-height with max-height - or something like that !

Comment: Actually, I have found that it is not max-height ---- it is __height__ . No matter how much the content is, it stays the same height. Long content will lead to overflow horizontally (you can check that by setting overflow:auto).

Comment: yay I also checked that, filed a bug to google, this is by no means correct.